# An error occurred saving import/export specification ''

Tags: excel, csv, ms-access-2016

I am new to MS-Access.

The title is the error I get when I try to import an excel sheet into a new table in Access 2016. Note the single empty quote is part of the error message.

I've tried reinstalling, playing around with import options, importing from a CSV, CSV with different encodings, checked the table in excel for errors or inconsistencies.

I have searched and searched without luck. Help would be appreciated.

ADDENDUM:
The CSV I've tried to import is:

```
CashAccountID,AccountDescription,BankName,BankAccountNumber
301,Primary Checking Account,MegaBank,9017765453
302,Money Market Account,Wells Gargle,3831157490
303,Payroll Account,MegaBank,9835320050
```

Comment: Certainly would have been nice to see the code you are using... so I will take a wild guess.... The 'empty quote' you see is actually two single quotes -- with nothing in between. Since there should have been 'something' in between, you have not properly specified the name?

Comment: The empty single quote happens when I try to import an excel sheet, while when I try to import a CSV it is named after the name I tried to use to save the import specification. That led me to think it is trying to save in a directory I have no rights for, which turned out to be a wrong assumption. I used the same excel on another computer and it works fine btw.

Comment: Are you using VBA to execute, or doing this manually? Isn't the error actually "An error occurred trying to save import/export specification..."? I found a bunch of topics that address the error, but don't know if you have already tried some of those suggestions?

Comment: I am using the wizard, and the error you've put is exactly the one I get. I've tried many of the those topics, none of them helped since I am not into programming. I just wanted to go through a tutorial and had to do the import.

Comment: If you are using a defined specification, then you may need to delete and recreate (that was one suggestion I found).

Comment: I came across this, however, it is not helpful since I am using the default wizard. Nor do I know how to edit or make a new spec using VB. I just want to use the default wizard for now.

Comment: I just encountered this same error attempting to add one (formerly skipped) column to an existing Import Specification. File still opens fine under old spec, but I now need the additional column. The error occurs when attempting to create a new specification with the additional column. Using ACCESS 2016

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error and, from trial and error, it appears the issue is related to the size of the Excel file you're importing from. I've had success by splitting the 70MB Excel file into two 35MB files before doing the same import into Excel.

The error message from MS Access is nonsensical - the problem occurs when we're not using an import/export specification at all (and nor are there any saved in the Access I'm running). I think we can put this failure and erroneous error message down as an MS Access bug.